# IBM Worklight Using Multiple HTML Files

Tags: android, html, ibm-mobilefirst

I am new to IBM Worklight . I have been using Android from past 1 year. I liked Worklight a lot and I feel I can do a lot more with it. I want to develop the app/game in HTML 5 using Worklight with Eclipse IDE. So I would like to know how to link all the required html,js and css files in one Worklight Project and dun it on various platforms...

Answer (score 2):

The worklight application is entirely works on IFrame concept i.e it is a single page application. Even though you have n number of pages it wont behave like web application. Just putting one page over another. Here in samples they gave information about paging. Calling the instance of page and removing the instance so it free up the memory occupied by the page instance. 
Go through 7.5 module for paging concept. There is another alternate solution for this. if you are not comfort with paging just design single page HTML file,

Advantage of Single Page HTML file:

- Avoiding multiple call to JS file for each page when tries to load.
- alignment and ordering of resources (css and js) is easy.

Answer (score 1):

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fstart%2Fc_gettingstarted.html
Check out module 7.5 and it's sample