# IBM worklight - Call worklight adapter from another html file

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

i've created another file testW.html beside main file and i've try to call worklight adapter in that file but it isn't work:
[image]

Here is my testW.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-dojo-config="isDebug: false, async: true, parseOnLoad: true, mblHideAddressBar: false" src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload="WL.Client.init({})">
<h1>Hello</h1>
<button type="button" onclick="LoginWS();">Click Me!</button>

<script src="js/PushAppRealmChallengeHandler.js"></script>
    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/test2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/configFb.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In here, LoginWS() is function call worklight adapter in test2.js,i've try call it in test2.html every thing is ok,how i call it in testW.html ?

Answer (score 1):

IBM Worklight applications are single page applications, however that doesn't mean you can't use HTML from other files. Take a look at the [Building a multi-page application](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/03_02_Building_a_multi_page_application.pdf) getting started module and the associated [sample code](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/BuildingMultiPageApplicationProject.zip).

**Related questions:**

- [IBM Worklight Using Multiple HTML Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444224/ibm-worklight-using-multiple-html-files)
- [type error: cannot call method 'invoke procedure' of undefined in worklight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15629323/type-error-cannot-call-method-invoke-procedure-of-undefined-in-worklight)
- [How to pass data between pages through worklight client API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474198/how-to-pass-data-between-pages-through-worklight-client-api)

Comment: have other way?if i do like tutorial for multi page i must to edit all my project

Comment: Unfortunately I have no alternative to achieve what you want without editing your code. The solution above is the only thing I recommend.